# Upload files with Sharepoint REST API and Javascript from outside of Sharepoint?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I need to upload files (and metadata) on demand without human action to a Sharepoint server.

Could I do with Sharepoint REST API form outside Sharepoint? Could I to launch a NodeJS server and access via PnPJS from outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can do REST API POST call to SharePoint from outside of SharePoint i.e. external web site. Lets say your external website is **"AAA"** and sending data to SharePoint site i.e. **"BBB"** - so in order to authenticate in SharePoint we need to generate the **client_id** and **client_secret** from SharePoint site - then while writing the POST call to SharePoint we need to use the **client_id** and **client_secret** code.

**Below are the steps how to generate "client_id" and "client_secret" from SharePoint:**

In order to achieve this access - we need to generate a **client_id** and **client_secret** from "https://BBB.sharepoint.com" site and uses that code in "AAA" site while sending the data "BBB" site.

There is a long steps how to the generate the **client_id** and **client_secret** code.

**Step 1: Register Add-In**

Go to the this page of your BBB site https://.SharePoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx

Here you will get: **client id** and **client secret**

Save this information in notepad.

**Step 2: Grant Permissions to Add-In**

Go to this page of your BBB site:

https://.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

Enter the "Client ID" in the App ID field and click on Lookup button

Now enter the below permission request in XML format:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="Read" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

**Step 3: Retrieve the Tenant ID**

In POST man tool do a GET request for this URL(BBB site):

https:///sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/client.svc/

From the Header section you will get the **realm** value which is nothing but your client ID.

So finally while you are sending the **client id** and **client secret** to the **AAA** site(your source site from where you are uploading the document), it should be in the below format:

```
client_id   ClientID@TenantID
client_secret   ClientSecret
```

**Example:**

```
client_id: 4b4276d0-74cd-4476-b66f-e7e326e2cb93@10267809-adcb-42b6-b103-c7c8190b3fed
client_secret: nuC+ygmhpadH93TqJdte++C37SUchZVK4a5xT9XtVBU=
```

Now when the other system here it is application **"AAA site"** performing the **POST** call to the "SharePoint site here it is https://BBB.sharepoint.com", they need to use these two **client_id** and **client_secret** key.

**Detailed explanation is here:**

https://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/

**Recommendation:**

Download the POST man tool from here  https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/

Do the sample POST request to SharePoint using this tool and the above **client_id** and **client_secret** code - then generate POST request API code whichever language suits for you almost all programming languages are available using the POST man tool - if you are working in C# - you can get the C# equivalent code for the POST call - then you can use the same piece of code in your actual application in Visual Studio or whichever tool you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Node JS to access SharePoint, we can use node-sp-auth to pass the authentication. node-sp-auth allows you to perform SharePoint unattended (without user interaction) http authentication with nodejs using different authentication techniques.

More information is here:

[node-sp-auth - nodejs to SharePoint unattended http authentication](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/node-sp-auth)